# How to print only the keys from a dictionary in one statement

Tags: python, dictionary, output

How would I go about printing only the keys from a dictionary in one print statement. 
The results which I would like to achieve is the following ...

```
Limit_list: Run till Abort, Kinetic, Single Scan
```

So far I have the following which I think is quite close.

```
new_dict = {'Run till Abort': 5, 'Kinetic': 3, 'Single Scan': 1}
print "Limit_list: {}".format(key for key, value in new_dict.iteritems())
```

The previous bit of code produces the following  results...

```
Limit_list: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x02C39878>
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this is getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Limit_list: {}".format(', '.join(new_dict))
```

Comment: We don't need the `.keys()` here... see the other answers